# should allow starting 30 pods per node

Tags: kubernetes

Running e2e-test on the local cluster kubernetes, with command:

```
go run hack/e2e.go -- --provider=local --test --check-version-skew=false --test_args="--host=https://192.168.1.5:6443 --ginkgo.focus=\[Feature:Performance\]"
```

Showing the errors:

```
[Feature:Performance] should allow starting 30 pods per node using { ReplicationController} with 0 secrets, 0 configmaps and 0 daemons [BeforeEach]
• Failure in Spec Setup (BeforeEach) [6.331 seconds]
[sig-scalability] Density
/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/_output/dockerized/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/test/e2e/scalability/framework.go:22
  [Feature:Performance] should allow starting 30 pods per node using { ReplicationController} with 0 secrets, 0 configmaps and 0 daemons [BeforeEach]
  /go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/_output/dockerized/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/test/e2e/scalability/density.go:554

  Expected error:
      <*errors.errorString | 0xc421733010>: {
          s: "Namespace e2e-tests-containers-ssgmn is active",
      }
      Namespace e2e-tests-containers-ssgmn is active
  not to have occurred

  /go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/_output/dockerized/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/test/e2e/scalability/density.go:466
------------------------------
SSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSJul 14 00:02:24.065: INFO: Running AfterSuite actions on all node
Jul 14 00:02:24.065: INFO: Running AfterSuite actions on node 1


Summarizing 2 Failures:

[Fail] [sig-scalability] Load capacity [BeforeEach] [Feature:Performance] should be able to handle 30 pods per node { ReplicationController} with 0 secrets, 0 configmaps and 0 daemons
/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/_output/dockerized/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/test/e2e/scalability/load.go:156

[Fail] [sig-scalability] Density [BeforeEach] [Feature:Performance] should allow starting 30 pods per node using { ReplicationController} with 0 secrets, 0 configmaps and 0 daemons
/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/_output/dockerized/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/test/e2e/scalability/density.go:466

Ran 2 of 998 Specs in 12.682 seconds
FAIL! -- 0 Passed | 2 Failed | 0 Pending | 996 Skipped --- FAIL: TestE2E (12.71s)
```

Seemingly, the local cluster Kubernetes has limitation of pods per node. How to fix this? The local cluster configuration is:

```
leeivan@master01:~/gowork/src/k8s.io/kubernetes$ kubectl get nodes
NAME       STATUS    ROLES     AGE       VERSION
master01   Ready     master    10d       v1.11.0
node01     Ready     <none>    10d       v1.11.0
node02     Ready     <none>    10d       v1.11.0
node03     Ready     <none>    10d       v1.11.0
node04     Ready     <none>    10d       v1.11.0
node05     Ready     <none>    10d       v1.11.0
leeivan@master01:~/gowork/src/k8s.io/kubernetes$ kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"11", GitVersion:"v1.11.0", GitCommit:"91e7b4fd31fcd3d5f436da26c980becec37ceefe", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2018-06-27T20:17:28Z", GoVersion:"go1.10.2", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"11", GitVersion:"v1.11.0", GitCommit:"91e7b4fd31fcd3d5f436da26c980becec37ceefe", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2018-06-27T20:08:34Z", GoVersion:"go1.10.2", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

Comment: Hi, you need to change the configuration of the Kubelet, Here is the flag `--max-pods int32`. https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/command-line-tools-reference/kubelet/#options

Comment: leeivan@master01:~$ kubelet --max-pods 30
Flag --max-pods has been deprecated, This parameter should be set via the config file specified by the Kubelet's --config flag. See https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/kubelet-config-file/ for more information.
I0714 10:49:53.909313    4801 feature_gate.go:230] feature gates: &{map[]}
I0714 10:49:53.909439    4801 feature_gate.go:230] feature gates: &{map[]}
F0714 10:49:53.909486    4801 server.go:245] error reading /var/lib/kubelet/pki/kubelet.key, certificate and key must be supplied as a pair

Comment: Cool, We need to use config file instead of bunch of flags, here is the spec https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/release-1.10/pkg/kubelet/apis/kubeletconfig/v1beta1/types.go

Comment: Here is the steps https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/reconfigure-kubelet/

Answer (score 1):

According to kubelet [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/command-line-tools-reference/kubelet/#options):

```
--max-pods int32
Number of Pods that can run on this Kubelet. (default 110)
```

So, 110 should be enough to pass the tests. But it is possible that test measures the real capacity of your nodes in terms of [Allocatable.CPU and Allocatable.Memory](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/72440a10e912de196cd4a80c759e17eccf5adb69/test/e2e/scalability/density.go#L479)

Also, before the test run, all the namespaces should be [deleted](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/72440a10e912de196cd4a80c759e17eccf5adb69/test/e2e/scalability/density.go#L482):

```
// Terminating a namespace (deleting the remaining objects from it - which
// generally means events) can affect the current run. Thus we wait for all
// terminating namespace to be finally deleted before starting this test.
```

Looks like one of your namespaces still was active, so the test failed.

Comment: Yes, thanks. After running: kubectl delete --all namespaces, the e2e-test is ok.

Comment: Do you know the requirement of cpu and memory for --ginkgo.focus=\[Feature:Performance\]?

Comment: I didn't find any requirements. You can check brief resource usage by running `top` or `htop` on the node with the pod during the test run.